# Light shading in the texture space in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to do a sort of  light baking.The idea is to "bake" a light into the texture in a pre-pass" so that in the main pass the texture in use is already shaded.I do it like this:

1. Create FBO and texture attachment with the size of the input texture.
2. Bind the input texture and render to the full screen quad.
3. Use the output texture (with the light baked into it) for my 3d mesh.

Currently it doesn't work.The result is black.I suppose it is related to the fact that the frag coordinates are different from what is expected when the vertices are transformed with model-view-projection matrix(in my case I output the normalized vertex coordinates right away).

Here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 420 core

layout(location = 0)  in vec4 position;//vertices are in range [-1,1]
layout(location = 1)  in vec2 uvs;
layout(location = 2)  in vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 MODEL_VIEW_MATRIX;
noperspective out vec2 vTexcoord;
out  vec3 Position;
out smooth vec3 Normal;
out gl_PerVertex
{
vec4 gl_Position;
};


void main() {
 vTexcoord = position.xy * 0.5  + 0.5;
 Normal = vec3(normalize(MODEL_VIEW_MATRIX * vec4(normal,0)));
 Position = vec3(MODEL_VIEW_MATRIX * position);
gl_Position = vec4( position.xy ,0.0 , 1.0 ); 
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
 void main() {
 ivec2 tsize = textureSize(COLOR_MAP_0, 0); 
vec2 texcoord = gl_FragCoord.xy * (1.0 / vec2(tsize));    
fResult = texture(COLOR_MAP_0  , texcoord) ;
fResult.rgb *=   pointlightType(0 , Position , Normal);// typical point light algo
 }
```

What do I miss here?Also in  my case depth buffer is not available.

**UPDATE:**

I solved it.The problem was some uniforms didn't pass to the shader. Since both source and target textures in my case are of the same dimensions the implementation was trivial.

Comment: "*real time GLSL based light baking*" That sounds like an oxymoron. The point of "baking" lighting is so that you're not computing it every frame. This allows you to do more complex lighting models than you could with non-real time graphics. If you're doing this in real time, every frame... why are you "baking" the lighting at all?

Comment: @NicolBolas "real-time" in my case means- doing it in the shader.Not prebaking on CPU .I am probably not going to do it on each frame, but even if I am, that is what I currently need.Do you have some useful input?

Comment: But on the second thought I think a better Header here would be "Texture space lightning" ;)

Comment: Indeed, implementation should be trivial. Half the lines of the shader are not even needed if source and destination have identical dimensions :) I do have to wonder what happens if you have 2 lights in this implementation, though. Usually you add the light terms for each light at each pixel rather than multiplying them together. If one light does not cover a pixel at all, it will multiply the previous light by 0.0...

Comment: You are right. Multiple lights should be added. Here it was just for the proof of concept  :)